# 2.8 Principled glass shader doesn't show any thickness?

Tags: shaders

I've got a principled glass shader and I've got the “screen space refractions” turned on. The glass has a thick base but you wouldn't know it to look at it? It's transparent ok and refracting the light ok, but the thicker base isn't apparent at all. Any ideas?

[image]

The principled shadernode looks like this

[image]

Wireframe shows that the cup has a base that isn't apparant in the render.
[image]

Comment: See if mesh object doesn't have negative scale and has its normals calculated inside. Also yes, if you want glass Transmission value in shader should be set to 1. So far you seem to have almost perfectly glossy shader

Comment: You can watch this blender tutorial. For transparent glass material. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lg_2OalFc8M
![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1zMY.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Right figured this out, sorry my fault it wasn't actually a transmission issue (that was set to 1, I must of been fiddling with it when I took the screen shot). So the issue did occur even with a transmission of 1.

The problem was I think with everything being a bit flat. So I added a few edge loops and added a bit of curve to the base, making it more parabolic(?). Also, made sure I didn't have any extra faces hidden in the base.

Also used all the setting recommended above (thanks everyone, much appreciated) ie.

- blend type to "Alpha Blend" in settings for the material
- See if mesh object doesn't have negative scale and has its normals calculated inside
- “screen space refractions” turned in settings for the material

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be working for me.

You could try switching the blend type to "Alpha Blend".

[image]

Eevee:

[image]

Cycles:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your Principled BSDF node doesn't have transmission set to 1, so all transparency you see should come from Blend mode setting in the material which is not glass shader. Set Transmission to 1 and see if it helps, if it doesn't then try to change between Blend modes in material settings.